# Android change imageButton when finger is hover on that

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm create simple application to work with custom buttom if finger is pressed or released and hover on that. in this simple `selector` project have 4 state for change background image, but i need to change this button when finger pointer is focus or hover on that but that does not work and only press work correctly in my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/logo"/>


    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/gohome" />


    <item android:state_focused="false"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/goran" />


    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

In touch UI there is no such thing as "hover". Hover is when your pointer is over a control. Without having a pointer, you cannot reproduce this step.

You can play with "focused", "pressed" and default.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/logo"/>

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/goran" />


    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo" />
</selector>
```